# Why do dogs try to cover their poop?

Tags: behaviour, dogs, excreta

It may seem obvious to us humans to hide our excreta, but this is not quite normal behavior for animals.

Interestingly, dogs have the habit to pee all over the place. It's know that they do so to mark their territory. So when they want to mark their territory, why do they cover up their poop?

I found an [old web article](http://hinessight.blogs.com/hinessight/2009/03/do-dogs-try-to-cover-or-spread-their-poop.html) where someone asks the same question, without getting a credible answer. He quotes a Yahoo Answers [answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080424192530AAfTEcK) making the following claim:

> This behavior is natural in dogs. They cover up their "waste" so that
>   an enemy does not find them, from the scent of the poop or pee. It is
>   an instinct handed down from wolves, who hid their scent by covering
>   up their feces in leaves, sticks, soil, or other nearby natural
>   materials. They also rolled in animal carcasses to hide the scent of
>   them. Your dog is just using her natural instinct to protect herself
>   from predators.
>
> Another things that dogs do, called marking, is when the dog pees in a
>   certain area. They do not cover it up, as it is marking a territory as
>   their own. Male dogs usually do this on trees, wooden posts,
>   furniture, and other things. Female dogs do this in heat. Dogs do not
>   poop to mark something, only pee. When you dog pees or poops and then
>   covers it up, this does not mean she is marking her territory. Just
>   wanted to add it so you don't get confused. :)

I find it hard to believe these two opposite claims. One time dogs want to mark their territory and the other time it's scared from predators. I know many dogs that do not cover their pee, but do cover their poop, sometimes even within the same walk (and so the same territory).

If this is true, why do dogs do both in the same walk?

On Wiki Answers I found [this answer](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_do_dogs_cover_their_pee_and_poop):

> The animals are not actually covering up the pee or pooh but spreading
>   their scent. This often happens with animals that are dominant (for
>   instance show dogs).

It's so that dogs never actually cover their poop anymore, they only perform some random scratches, throwing a little sand on the turd, sometimes even nothing. That fact makes this answer quite more likely than the previous one.

Another take that's similar to the previous one is [this one](http://blogs.dogster.com/dog_tip_of_the_day/2008/10/21/dog-tip-why-do-dogs-scratch-the-ground-after-they-do-the-doo/) from Dogster:

> So, why do dogs scratch with their hind legs after defecating? You
>   might think the dog is trying to cover up his poop like a cat does,
>   but it’s actually a way to mark territory, with the scratch marks in
>   the ground pointing to the scent the dog has left.

I also found [an eHow article](http://www.ehow.com/about_6620614_do-scratch-ground-after-defecating_.html#ixzz2Rm5BDGql) on this subject. It seems to agree with the previous two explanations, but is more detailed.

> It is normal for dogs of both sexes to vigorously kick the ground with
>   their hind legs after defecating. This is called scraping or peeling
>   out. Some dogs will also do it after urinating. Dogs are descended
>   from wolves, which also perform this behavior. It is not a bad habit,
>   but a vital part of a dog leaving a visual message and scent message
>   to any other dogs that happen to pass by.

They also say that the specific reason why they spread scent with their paws is because paws just contain a lot of scent.

> Dog paws contain scent glands. There are also glands in between the
>   toes. The action of scraping the paws against the ground helps release
>   the scent inside of the glands. Dogs scrape the ground in order to
>   increase their scent on the area near the feces pile, according to
>   veterinarian Dr. Justine Lee. Before domestication, dogs wandered in
>   large territories. One vital way to communicate with other wandering
>   dogs is through scent marking. This instinct has not been bred out of
>   the domestic dog.

So, which theory is the most valid? I tent to go for the scent one. Any additions?

Comment: ...maybe because dogs that didn't do that were more likely to get sick (or get members of their pack sick) and die, giving an evolutive edge to the ones that randomly started to do that. Or maybe it is so the smell doesn't cover another more important smells. Or maybe we humans selected the ones who did, because...well, obviously we prefer the ones who bury their feces without even training them to do it. Or maybe, the ones who buried them just happened to survive in greater numbers, but it may not be a relevant trait in said survival (correlation doesn't imply causation)

Answer (score 6):

I cannot find any definite articles on why there would be a reason for this behaviour other than the same ones that you have mentioned in your article. It could be because it wants to mark its territory or the dog wants to hide its scent.

One point that I would also like to add is force of habit. As Charles Darwin (the father of evolutionary biology) had said in his book titled "The expression of emotion in man and animals"

> ‘Certain complex actions are of direct or indirect service under
>   certain states of the mind, in order to relieve or gratify certain
>   sensations, desires, etc.; and whenever the same state of mind is
>   induced, however feebly, there is a tendency through the force of
>   habit and association for the same movements to be performed, though
>   they may not then be of the least use’ ([reference 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Expression_of_the_Emotions_in_Man_and_Animals) and [reference 2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1279921/)).

It is more of a guess that we make when we see them hide their faeces but in the end, there may not be a reason at all but a habit that do not serve much purpose passed on through evolution. It is left upto our own liberty as to guess what the exact reason is.